# how to use sharedPreferences in Firebase PhoneAuth in Flutter to keep the user logged in

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, sharedpreferences

I want to keep user logged in after OTP verification in Phone Auth. The code is working fine with phone OTP verification. I want to use sharedPreferences to keep user logged in. Every time, I have to start from the login screen.

```
onPressed: () async {
                      try {
                        PhoneAuthCredential credential =
                            PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                                verificationId: MyPhone.verify, smsCode: code);
                        // Sign the user in (or link) with the credential
                        await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);


                        await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); 


                        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const WelcomeScreen(),
                            ),
                            (route) => false);
                      } catch (e) {
                        print("wrong OTP");
                      }
                    },
```

kindly guide how to use shared preferences in the above mentioned code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:therapist_app/authentication/phone.dart';
import 'package:therapist_app/authentication/verify.dart';
import 'package:therapist_app/mainScreens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'global/global.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Therapist App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routes: {
        'phone': (context) => MyPhone(),
        'verify': (context) => MyVerify(),
        'home_screen': (context) => HomeScreen()
      },
      home: const MyPhone(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the code of your main widget? it seems that the issue is also in your routing to the entry point of your app

Comment: @CarlosSandoval, I have just shared the main.dart file, kindly go through it

Comment: thanks, I can think that your onPressed method at the beginning of your post is on your MyPhone() view?

Comment: @CarlosSandoval, No, its on verify screen.